# How to run installing php code?

Tags: magento-1.8, php, install, sql

I am using [**Online module creator**](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) to create a table in admin panel.

I added the sql query as needed to create the table but I don't know what to write in the field `Run Installing Php Code`.

Please see the screenshot below for clear understanding

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing.
I haven't used that module creator a lot but I assume that is the php code that is ran when the install script is executed. It can be useful if you want to create entity instances or you want to modify some config values or anything else that comes to mind. If you are just creating a module to manage some entities then you don't need to put anything in there.
But just to make sure, put something / anything in there, and when you download the extension you create then look in it's files and folders for the text you entered. If you identify the file you can get a better idea about what it does.

Comment: Marius, the table has not been created. when I check the file it is something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/9RQ39/). It is in `sql/queries-setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` file of my module.

Comment: @Mr_Green Clear the cache for the sql to run. And on the other hand I was right about what that field you asked about does. It should contain the php code that should run on install. In most cases you don't need it.

Comment: Marius, I did same.. still I can't see the table in database and also the section in catolog_product attributes. Does having a different data type for a column in admin and sql query effect this? because I have a column with TIME_STAMP as datatype in sql and DATE as data type in module creator..

Comment: Please check this file for understanding what settings I did.. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0hddygxq5jsr0k/Magento%20Module%20Creator%20_%20SilkSoftware.pdf).. I hope I am not taking much time of yours.. FYI, I re-indexed and cleared the cache from browser and magento folder.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea why it doesn't work. maybe you should ask the developers for support. I can recommend you this: https://github.com/tzyganu/moduleCreator. On that I can offer support :).

Comment: sorry to ask you without even looking in to your module creator... (wasted lot of time) does it add a attribute section as I want or it just add a section in main menu of admin panel?

Comment: It has the optiion to link the entities you create with the products. Many to many. This means that in the product edit page you will have a tab with the availabla entities and you can select as many as you want. And the other way around. In the entity edit page you will see a tab with all the products and you can select as many as you want.

Comment: Checking your module creator looks nice to me.. I will soon implement my own attribute section (doing some other work now) Thanks :)

Comment: I am tried to create module with your ultimate module creator but I couldn't save it.. can you help me please? [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39342/developers-of-magento-ios)

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, and I won't be for a while. Send me an email with  the error and I will check it. You Wiil find the email address in the files of the extension.

Comment: Marius, I have created a module using your module creator. It is working fine in my PC but when published online, the admin panel is redirecting to 404 page whenever I click on the created modules system menu. please help..

Comment: And even the modules which I created on my PC are not working for some of my colleagues.. vice versa.

Comment: Log out then re log in. And don't use uppercase letters in the module name. So `Modulename` is ok, `ModuleName` is not OK. There is a small bug.

Comment: Marius, sorry to disturb you.. I think I haven't merged complete files of the module in the server. I am checking now..